# How does one rotate relative to the camera in openGL or more specifically LWJGL?

Tags: java, c++, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I am making a 3d game with `LWJGL`.  In this game, whenever I press an arrow key, I want the screen to rotate in that direction, regardless of the current orientation.  I am struggling to implement this in code.  Using three `glRotatef` functions based off of a rotation vector3f, does not accomplish this.  Rotating up and down work because `glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0)` is called first, but left and right only work when your not looking up or down.  If you are, you rotate around a universal y axis, and camera spins.  I saw that another implementation could use `gluLookAt()`, but I imagine I would encounter the same problem.

**EDIT**
   I thought I solved my issue by changing the order by which glRotatef()'s where called depending on the direction I want to rotate.  I thought this would work because in my game, I will only be rotating one axis at a time.  It worked somewhat but in some orientations it doesn't.

```
      if(updown){
             glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
             glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
        } else if(leftright){
             glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
             glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
        }
        glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
```

Comment: Take a look at chapter 2 and 3 of the Red Book, it might help you wrap your mind around the order of matrix operations in opengl: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/

Comment: You should answer your own question if you found a solution to it. It's easier for people if the answer and question are individual.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I will consider that when I actually solve this issue.  My solution in fact didn't work

Answer (score 0):

gluLookAt would probably get you there much quicker, but you would need to manually rotate the eye coordinate about the origin coordinate. With gluLookAt you also need to calculate an up vector if you plan to rotate around all 3 axes.

I have a hunch you just need to add a glTranslate before you do your glRotate so that the camera has something to orbit around.

If you show some code you might be able to get more help.

Comment: Thank  you so much for the quick response.  It is not an issue of a misplaced glTranslate.  My understanding of gluLookAt() is that it takes a loation for your eye and a location of another point that your eye looks at.  This second point doesn't matter how far it is from the eye. And lastly, three numbers that determine the orientation of the camera (which way is up).  Is this true.  If so, then how might I go about the math of implementing this.  I would imagine I would use some sort of trig, but I am unsure how to do so in 3d space.

Comment: Also, why is the up vector defined by three numbers?  Isn't it limited to a single rotation around the line created by the eye and what it looks at.

Answer (score 0):

I am over this issue and have moved on.  Because I am only going to rotate one axis 90 degrees at a time, I went through all 64 possible orientations and applied the necesary transforations manualy.